# Monitoring Excessive User Home Directory Growth

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script for a school assignment that will check and see if any of the non-administrative user home directories have increased in size by more than 100 MB in a single 20 minute period.

If any of the users' home directories have increased by more than 100 MB then send the root an email.  This needs to be an automated routine.

This is what I did so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
#

DIR=`ls -d /home/*`
Size=0
for DIR in $DIR
do
   Size[index]=`du -skh ${DIR}`

done

 while sleep 5; do      
   for DIR in $DIR
  do
    NEW_SIZE=0
    NEW_SIZE=`du -skh ${DIR} `
    DIFF=$((SIZE-NEW_SIZE))
    echo $DIFF  
      if [ $DIFF -eq 0 ]
      then
          mail -s "Subject" root
     fi

    done
done
```

but I get the following syntax error:

> Error : Line 19 : 580K: value too great for base ( error token is "580K")

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Many issues:

- `for DIR in $DIR` changes the value of `$DIR`.  This might work
  the first time, but the second time you execute this statement,
  `$DIR` will be the *last* directory in `/home`, not the entire list.

  - Why not just say `for DIR in /home/*`?
- `index` is never set.
- This is harmless, but there’s no reason to set `NEW_SIZE=0` just
  before setting `NEW_SIZE` to another value in the next line.
- `SIZE` is never set.

You might want to learn some elementary debugging techniques.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of pointers:

1. `du -skh ${DIR}` will produce something that looks like `23M Example/`, whereas you probably want it to just be a number that you can then compute later. Maybe use `cut` to remove the directory name, and don't use -h, because you want a computer readable number, not a human readable number.
2. `DIFF=$((SIZE-NEW_SIZE))` doesn't look right. Try `` DIFF=`expr $NEW_SIZE - $SIZE` ``
3. Then, you probably want to test the value of DIFF against something like 100MB, i.e. 100000000 bytes (more or less): `[[ $DIFF -ge 100000000 ]]` "if the value of DIFF is greater than or equal to 100000000 bytes…"

This will depend on your OS, especially the flags for the test. I can't remember which but I think Mac uses -g for greater than, while linux uses -gt. -ge I think is always greater than or equal to. Google it.

Perhaps it would be easier to store the sizes of the directories for each 20 minute slice in a log file, and to have your script append to the log file and compare it with the previous log entry. Then you could run it as a straight up cronjob rather than a constant `while sleep` job. Could be a bit more faffing around though.

Comment: it gave me expr: syntax error

Comment: That could be because you're not giving it raw numbers. Try using expr on its own. Enter `expr 10 - 8`, it should return `2`. Now try entering `expr 10MB dir1/ - 25MB`, which is roughly equivalent to what you're giving it from the look of your script. Syntax error.